# sending a variable from one php file to another and for displaying the variable value in a third file

Tags: php, html

bookincome.php takes in a couple of inputs and bi.php calculates the total net income based on the values taken from bookincome.php and displays a table that contains all the given values from the user and the calculated total book income($tnibeforetax) value. Now I have a table in my report1.php and i want to display the calulated $tnibeforetax value in it and i am not able to display the value in that table in report1.php. Please help

The code for bookincome.php :

```html
<?php
// start session
session_start();
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title> Book Income </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <center>
      <h2>BOOK INCOME AS PER TRIAL BALANCE ENTRY </h3>
    </center>
    <form name='form' action="bi.php" method='post' autocomplete='off' target="_blank" [....]>
      <table cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Book Income as per Trial Balance: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="bi" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['bi'])) ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Late Adjustment 1: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="la1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['la1'])) ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Late Adjustment 2: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="la2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['la2'])) ?>"><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Late Adjustment 3: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="la3" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['la3'])) ?>"><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Audit Adjustment 1: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="aa1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['aa1'])) ?>"><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Audit Adjustment 2: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="aa2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['aa2'])) ?>"><br> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <br>
          <td align="left">Audit Adjustment 3: </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="aa3" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['aa4'])) ?>"><br> </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <br>
      <center> <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button> </center>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Following is the code of bi.php:

```html
<?php
// start session
session_start();

   $bi = $_POST['bi'];
   $la1 = $_POST['la1'];
   $la2 = $_POST['la2'];
   $la3 = $_POST['la3'];
   $aa1 = $_POST['aa1'];
   $aa2 = $_POST['aa2'];
   $aa3 = $_POST['aa3'];
   
   $tnibeforetax= $bi + $la1 + $la2 + $la3 + $aa1 + $aa2 + $aa3;
   
   $_SESSION['tnibeforetax'] = $tnibeforetax; 
    
?>
  <html>

  <head>
    <style>
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table style="width:50%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="70%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center"> Amount </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Book Income as per trail Balance </td>
        <td align="right">
          <?php echo $bi ; ?> </td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
  if($la1!=0)
  {
   echo '<tr><td> Late Adjustment1 </td> ';
   echo '<td align="right">'. $la1 . '</td><tr>';
  }
 ?>
      <?php 
  if($la2!=0)
  {
   echo '<tr><td> Late Adjustment2 </td>';
   echo '<td align="right">'. $la2 . '</td></tr>';
  }
 ?>
      <?php 
  if($la3!=0)
  {
   echo '<tr><td> Late Adjustment3 </td> ';
   echo '<td align="right">'. $la3 . '</td></tr>';
  }
 ?>
      <?php 
  if($aa1!=0)
  {
   echo '<tr><td> Audit Adjustment1 </td> ';
   echo '<td align="right">'. $aa1 . '</td></tr>';
  }
 ?>
      <?php 
  if($aa2!=0)
  {
   echo '<tr><td> Audit Adjustment2 </td></tr> ';
   echo '<tr><td align="right">'. $aa2 . '</td></tr>';
  }
 ?>
      <?php 
  if($aa3!=0)
  {
   echo '<tr><td> Audit Adjustment3 </td>';
   echo '<td align="right">'. $aa3 . '</td></tr>';
  }
 ?>
      <tr>
        <td> Total Net Income before tax as per Income Statement </td>
        <td align="right">
          <?php echo $tnibeforetax ; ?> </td>
      </tr>
```

The code for report1.php:

```html
<?php
// start session
session_start();

$tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['$tnibeforetax'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 table, th, td 
 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:50%" align="center" >
 <tr>
  <td style="font-weight:bold" colspan="2" ><font color="darkgreen" > Income from Business & Proffession:</td></font>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> Net Income before tax as per Income Statement </td>
  <td width="25%"> <?php echo "$" . $tnibeforetax; ?></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Typo on this line `$tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['$tnibeforetax'];`

Comment: whats the typo?

Comment: the `$` sign. It should be `$_SESSION['tnibeforetax']` same as before you used for set

Comment: yeaahh got it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are just `checking` not `checking and printing` so change here and for all below

```
<td><input type="number" name="bi" value="<?php $_POST['bi'] ?? '' ?>"></td>
```

Here `$_POST['bi'] ?? ''` is same for  `isset($_POST['bi']) ? $_POST['bi'] : ''` in php 7.

Add same check for `bi.php`

```
$bi = $_POST['bi'] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['$tnibeforetax'];
```

No `$` inside the value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is because you set the session with value `tnibeforetax` but getting it with `$tnibeforetax` please replace the above code in your 3rd file i.e `report1.php`.

```
 <?php
    // start session
    session_start();

    $tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['tnibeforetax'];

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the output of the result inside the `value` attribute.

`<td><input type="number" name="bi" value="<?php $_POST['bi'] ?? '' ?>"></td>` to

`<td><input type="number" name="bi" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['bi']) ? $_POST['bi'] : '' ?>"></td>`

The same for `la1`, `la2` etc.

With `short_open_tag=On` in php.ini file it can be just `<?= isset($_POST['bi']) ? $_POST['bi'] : '' ?>`. In PHP 7 it can be just `<?= $_POST['bi'] ?? '' ?>`.

`$tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['$tnibeforetax'];` in report1.php must be

```
$tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['tnibeforetax'];
```

Please use more understandable names for variables. The name of the variable must match the data stored in it as clearly as possible. For ex., instead of `bi` use `bookIncome`.

Answer (score 0):

[please remove the $ sign from ['$tnibeforetax'] that is written as $tnibeforetax = $_SESSION['$tnibeforetax'] in report1 code section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnilT.png)